# How do I activate 3 different functions in sequence in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying this for a while now, but i can't get it to work.
My problem: I have 3 functions (1 to make an a div smaller, 1 to renew the div, 1 to enlarge the div) which are activated by a mouseclick. But they activate at the same time, meaning the 1st (making the div smaller) is skipped due to the 2nd (renewing the div).
The 2nd function calls a php function to reload the data in the div.
Below are the 3 functions:

```
function reduceView(Parent){
    $(Parent).find('#details').hide("slow", function(){
        // Animation complete.
    });
    // get width and Extend
    $(Parent).find("#" + Parent.ID + "").width("250px");
    var width = $(Parent).find("#" + Parent.ID + "").css("width");
    $(Parent).animate({
        width: width
    }, 500, function(){
        // Animation complete.
    });
}

function renewWindow(Parent){
    $(":animated").promise().done(function(){
        PHP.execute(Parent.id + "/home");
        $(Parent).find("div[class='Item-list']").remove();
        $(Parent).find("div[id='details']").remove();
        $(Parent).find("div[id='confirmDialog']").remove();
        $(Parent).append(PHP.response);
        initJquery();
        initEvents();
    });
}

function enlargeView(Parent){
    $(Parent).promise().done(function(){
        $(Parent).find('#details').show("slow", function(){
            // Animation complete.
        });
        // get width and Extend
        $(Parent).find("#" + Parent.ID + "").width("683px");
        var width = $(Parent).find("#" + Parent.ID + "").css("width");
        $(Parent).animate({
            width: width
        }, 500, function(){
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
}
```

Any clue how to get these 3 to work in order?
The 'initJquery' and 'initEvents' see to the fact that the .click and the like are reinitialized.
Thanks in advance!!

Ps. if i missed any info that you might need, don't hesitate to ask!!

EDIT: Below is the code that calls the functions

```
$(".selecter").click(function() {
    var Element = this;
    var ID = Element.id;
    var Parent = $(Element).closest(".drag-div")[0];
    reduceView(Parent);
    renewWindow(Parent);

    $(":animated").promise().done(function(){
        PHP.execute(Parent.id + "/details?" + Parent.id + "id="+ID);
        $(Parent).find('#details').html(PHP.response);
        enlargeView(Parent);
        initJquery();
    });
    $(Element).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: can u show post the code which activates the functions?

Comment: Javascript functions should execute in the order in which you call them. Functions don't execute concurrently.

Comment: You should call the next successive function inside the completion callback of the function that comes before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're applying multiple animations, and then getting the promise for the animation you want using $(":animated") selector. There isn't enough code in your answer to run it, but my guess is that the closure in renewWindow is being triggered by the wrong promise object - possibly one on the page that isn't even related to this functionality.

Try returning the promise object you want to key off of from the first function, like so:

```
function reduceView(Parent){
    var promise = $(Parent).find('#details').hide("slow", function(){
        // Animation complete.
    }).promise();
    // get width and Extend
    $(Parent).find("#" + Parent.ID + "").width("250px");
    var width = $(Parent).find("#" + Parent.ID + "").css("width");
    $(Parent).animate({
        width: width
    }, 500, function(){
        // Animation complete.
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Then, renewWindow can consume that promise:

```
function renewWindow(Parent, promise){
    promise.done(function(){
        PHP.execute(Parent.id + "/home");
        $(Parent).find("div[class='Item-list']").remove();
        $(Parent).find("div[id='details']").remove();
        $(Parent).find("div[id='confirmDialog']").remove();
        $(Parent).append(PHP.response);
        initJquery();
        initEvents();
    });
}
```

This way you know that the promise you're triggering your function with is the one you used to hide the div.

Comment: Thanks! With a callback and the promise i have been succesfull! :D